# Find Out Seed Number in Generating some random number

Tags: r, statistics

How can we extract seed number in generating some random number. For example in the following example we generate 100 random standard normal with seed number=1234.

```
set.seed(1234)
x<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1)
```

Now we want to know, how can we find out seed number when we generate these random number:

```
x<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1)
```

Comment: it's not really feasible to go backward in this way.  You might want to search SO for `set.seed` and `Random.seed`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614314/can-i-get-seed-somehow

Comment: thanks, so there is no straightforward way to find out the seed number and that link you shared is a substitute for the problem. Thanks

Comment: Note that: There is no guarantee that different values of seed will seed the RNG differently, although any exceptions would be extremely rare.

Comment: Obvious question: why?  Just add `set.seed` before running your code.  If you didn't do so, and also failed to save the vector `x` you generated, well shame on you :-).  (because if you have `x` you can pseudoreproduce the sequence by `y<-x[1:N]`