# Finding the used seed in cv.glm()

Tags: r, glm, seed, cross-validation

I am applying the `cv.glm()` function from the `{boot}` package. The command is working perfectly fine, but I am trying to obtain the seed on which the my K fold cross validation was established to be able to reproduce the results. Here's an example (from the MASS package data) of what I have:

```
data(mammals, package="MASS")
model <- glm(log(brain) ~ log(body), data = mammals)
result <- cv.glm(mammals, model, K=10)
```

When I execute `result$seed` I get a vector of length 626.
What seed have I exactly used here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Set the seed before conducting the analysis.

Comment: Oh I see, that worked. Thanks. Would you like to rewrite it as an answer? :)

Comment: I expect it is the same as the `.Random.seed` variable. It is not possible to get the *single* value of `set.seed` that produced this, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19614429/269476

Comment: I thought so, but this would be a good explanation if someone is struggling with `cv.glm()` in particular