# How do I retrieve the seed in random processes in R language?

Tags: r, random

In the following process:

```
x <- c(1:10)
for(i in 1:20){
   y <- sample(x)
   print(y)
}
```

How do I retrieve the seed used at each step? (I don't want to pre-establish it). Is there something like "get.seed()"?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19614429/8580595

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get.seed() somehow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614314/can-i-get-seed-somehow)