# How to get.seed()?

Tags: r, random, simulation, random-seed

I run a lot of simulations, and we want them to be random, yet replicable.

I would like to be able to `get.seed()` after I perform an operation.  I would like the value to return to be a numeric integer that I could later call as `set.seed(NNNN);`

In mathematics, there is a fundamental principle of inverses in algebra, and it also relates to programming algebra.  For example:

```
N = 3;
pnorm(N);
qnorm( pnorm( N ) );
```

Where is the inverse function for `set.seed()`?  Where is `get.seed()`?

So with `set.seed` I can pass in a NULL entry and it will "generate" a random seed for the random-ness to follow (which dies after some "unspecified" time).

```
rnorm(5);
set.seed(NULL); rnorm(5);
set.seed(123); rnorm(5);
set.seed(NULL); rnorm(5);
set.seed(123); rnorm(5);
```

UNDER the hood, there is a global variable that looks like some sort of digest object of integers:

```
set.seed(NULL); .Random.seed;
set.seed(123); .Random.seed;
```

So where is the reverse mapping of `.Random.seed` to the INTEGER that is input `NNNN`?

Where is `get.seed()`?

Certainly I can randomly pick a value for NNNN and store and report, but that is me "introducing" an extra level of random-ness in the research and simulation that I may not want.

Under the hood, when `NULL` was passed, the seed has to be generated.  Is it going directly to the "Mersenne-Twister" without generating a NNNN value first?  Is it not reversible?

It is "as-if" I was given a function `deg2rad` without its inverse `rad2deg`.  Is there something under the hood I am missing?

Has someone written a `get.seed()` function in custom form to address this issue.  Something like this "other missing function" in BaSe R.

```
#' rgb2col
#'
#' Reverse the built-in grDevices::col2rgb function
#'
#' @param x vector of colors
#'
#' @return vector of colors in RGB hex format
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#'
#' rgb2col( col2rgb("red") );
#' rgb2col( col2rgb("red", alpha=TRUE) );
#' rgb2col( col2rgb("#FF0000FF", alpha=TRUE) );
#' rgb2col( col2rgb("#FF000033", alpha=TRUE) );
#'
rgb2col = function(x)
  {
  # reverses col2rgb function
  x.n = dim(x)[1];
  if(x.n == 4)
    {
    x.rgb = t(x[1:4,]) /255;
    grDevices::rgb(   as.numeric(x.rgb[,1]),
                      as.numeric(x.rgb[,2]),
                      as.numeric(x.rgb[,3]),
                      as.numeric(x.rgb[,4]),
      names=rownames(x.rgb) );
    } else {
            x.rgb = t(x[1:3,]) /255;
            grDevices::rgb( x.rgb, names=rownames(x.rgb) );
            }
  }
```

Comment: I think you got to the core of it:  this is not reversible.  _If and when you set a seed_ subsequent draws are 'deterministic' given that seed and reproducible.  But nothing else holds: you would have to dump the whole `.Random.seed` vector and, as I recall, it is not designed for this either.  In short, use `set.seed()` to set a baseline, then return, if you wish to, to that baseline.

Comment: So it's like an md5 hash, it is only one direction?  When `NULL` is passed, they don't go to `NNNN` first, they just go right to the seed generator?

Comment: I guess I could write my own functions `setSeed(` and `getSeed(` that forces the inbetween `NNNN` step?

Comment: Not sure. It might be easier to just use a different generator if you have different requirements.

Comment: I have seen that post, doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: I think it does because Hong and I try to explain the same thing: you can't have what you ask for under the internal RNG engine which is why there is no `get.seed()`.  Suggest to close as duplicate.